# [React]: UseRef to scrollIntoView last message of different threads IF needed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am having an issue where in my app, the user can load different message threads, and if that thread has grown longer than the viewing area, (ie, needs a scrollbar to view bottom messages), then I want to auto scroll to the last message.

Using a `useRef` I tag a place right after my map like so:

```
currentList.map(elem => ( <div>{elem}</div>) )
<div ref={messagesRef} /> // <------Here
```

My issue is that by using the `useRef.current` field, my message thread selections is always one step behind, because the ref updates from null after mount and therefore is behind what I am actively selected on.  Also because of this, I had to force a check to make sure I didn't try to do anything to that null ref like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (messagesRef.current) { // < -- make sure we're not null
    scrollToBottom();
  }
}, [messagesRef]);
```

scrollToBottom method is this:

```
const scrollToBottom = () => {
  messagesRef.current.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth",
    block: "nearest" // <-- only scroll this div, not the parent as well
  });
};
```

As I said before, my goal is to let the user select different threads, and for any thread that needs to be scrolled to the bottom, I'll do that for them.  However, as they select a thread, when logging out the status of the ref `messagesRef.current`, it is rendering 1 thread behind what is selected.  I checked this by outputting the result of `messagesRef.current.parentNode.offsetHeight`.

Each thread that didn't need to be scrolled, had an offsetHeight less than my message window height ( 500 in my case ).  While the one that did need to be scrolled, was larger than my window height.

Very frustrating trying to rely on this useRef, when the current value is not updating with my selections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I wasn't able to solve the issue with useRef being one step behind my selections, I was able to resolve my ultimate issue and produce the result I was looking for; autoscrolling to the last message, IF we need to.

While useRef.current was behind, what wasn't behind was the state of my message threads. So by using that to check when I need to scroll, problem was solved.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // be sure we need to scroll, length of 2 equates to the visual size of the message box
  if (currentList.length > 2) { // <-- more than 2, we've grown outside the window 
    scrollToBottom();
  }
  }, [currentList]); // <- update dependency array to state, not the Ref
```

Here is my final working version.  You can see the thread start out empty, then as you select on the buttons, the thread will scroll to the bottom, if needed.

https://codesandbox.io/s/userefissue-v86kq

Hope this helps someone down the road, and if there are any tips on how to keep my ref updated with my current selection, I'd love to hear the solution!